# Create interactive image - plotting points onto a map

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, maps, interactive

I wish to create a interactive map in Python.

- The map will be a JPG image with points plotted on.
- Each point will identify a key event and display text when clicked.

I essentially wish to something akin to this http://lotrproject.com/map/

Here is the raw map.

[image]

This is what I wish to create.

[image]

I have found some tutorials in Java that may achieve this, but I wish to learn Python and thus create this in Python.

**Would this be possible in Python**, if so, could you give me advice on how to achieve this? Links to tutorials for beginners or detailed replies are appreciated!